# Android SDL2 Startup Crash

Tags: android, android-ndk, sdl-2

Can somebody please help me? I have a test SDL2 application which runs on my phone just fine. I took a copy of the sample app and began porting in code from my own application which builds and links just fine.

My application crashes on startup with the below error in the log (last line):

```
05-22 16:24:48.271 14834-14834/org.libsdl.app D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/org.libsdl.app-13/libSDL2.so 0x42b0fb20
05-22 16:24:48.271 14834-14834/org.libsdl.app D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.libsdl.app-13/libSDL2.so 0x42b0fb20
05-22 16:24:48.271 14834-14834/org.libsdl.app D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/org.libsdl.app-13/libmain.so 0x42b0fb20
05-22 16:24:48.281 14834-14834/org.libsdl.app A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000c (code=1), thread 14834 (org.libsdl.app)
```

I have commented out my main() code and replaced this content with the main() from the sample app and it still crashes.

I'm faced with the long-winded task of incrementally including source files and components until I can identify the cause.

Does anybody know of a common cause for this please?

I am doing a clean build and run each time.

Comment: It looks like you have logcat's output filtering on. There should be a stack trace in the output after the 'fatal signal' line, which is visible if you select 'No filters' in logcat. Decoding that stack trace will hopefully make your search a bit narrower.

Comment: @bullsy Thanks for that. Yes I did find more information in the logs the other night and it looks as though there is a crash in some of my code where global class objects are being constructed. So - a bug in my code in other words - something I should be able to fix myself and nothing specific to SDL or NDK in general. Add your comment as an answer and I will accept it because that's exactly the conclusion I came to. I didn't know how to turn filtering on/off so I may have turned it off and seen the full trace by accident.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to narrow it down. It's easy to miss the trace because the filtering defaults to 'Show only this application'. Debugging a crash on load like this can be tricky, but the newly built-in C++ debugging tools in Android Studio are helpful. If you're not already using them and are still working on this issue, you may want to give the Android Studio 2.2 Preview a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have logcat's output filtering on. There should be a stack trace in the output after the 'fatal signal' line, which is visible if you select 'No filters' in logcat. Decoding that stack trace will hopefully make your search a bit narrower.